# axconfig: port 1and 2 not active

Tags: 12.04, python

I try to install reddit on my ubuntu server but I get an error: Please look in the terminal :

```
[+] including definitions from Makefile.py
python setup.py build
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
python setup.py build_ext --inplace  # copy the .so files from cython into the source tree
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/sgm.so -> r2/lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/wrapped.so -> r2/lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/db/_sorts.so -> r2/lib/db
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/mr_tools/_mr_tools.so -> r2/lib/mr_tools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/utils/_utils.so -> r2/lib/utils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/utils/comment_tree_utils.so -> r2/lib/utils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Cfilters.so -> 
# see above
rm -f build/public/static/sprite-reddit.png build/public/static/reddit.css
python r2/lib/nymph.py build/public/static/css/reddit.less build/public/static/sprite-reddit.png > build/public/static/css/reddit.less.tmp
lessc build/public/static/css/reddit.less.tmp > build/public/static/reddit.css.tmp
axconfig: port 1 not active
axconfig: port 2 not active
make: *** [build/public/static/reddit.css] Error 1
```

Please help me to fix it.
Node and Nodejs both already installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try install 'nodejs' or 'node' :

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

or

```
 apt-get install node
```

Comment: both already installed.

Comment: @EsembledINTL: Please clarify that in your question for future readers and (potential) answerers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Then, try next :

1. sudo apt-get remove node
2. Only Download nodejs from http://nodejs.org/ or using git from https://github.com/nodejs/node but make sure you install the stable branch.
   For installing please follow the README.md

> git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
>
> cd node
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

3. After installing then set the environment variables 
   export PATH=$PTATH:/home/user/pathtonode/

Comment: At line 3 I get this: -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: The terminal not found /.configure and looks to not exist. I do something wrong ?